# Placeholder Value for Dictionary? (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, dictionary, arcgis, placeholder

I am working on a bit of code, where I need to convert the values in a table column to numbers, and i'm using a dictionary to keep it concise.

```
colodesc = {'Lawn': 1, 'Unpaved': 2, 'Paved': 3, 'Unknown': 4, '': 4}#DEBUGING#
    cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(co_reh_sum_mem, "Cleanout_Location_Area_Description__Lawn_Unpaved_Paved_")
    for row in cursor:
        row = colodesc[row[0]]
        cursor.updateRow([row])
```

The column values will be either Lawn, Unpaved, Paved, or Unknown - but sometimes other values may have been entered into the column. I want to convert any of these to the value 4 (unknown), but it is not practical to create a key for all possible input values. Is there a way to have a "placeholder" dictionary key for any value other than those already defined?

Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: Use the `dict.get()` method - `row = colodesc.get(row[0], 4)`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you internet_user and jasonharper!